# read from file and store

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file and store it using hashmap, but there is this error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0". My input has two columns separated by space something like
Name ID so on with different entries. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Input:**

```
Mary ID
Mary Lastname
Mary Place
Mary DOB
Mary Homepage
Mary Postcode
John ID
John Lastname
John Place
John DOB
John Homepage
John Postcode
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

class ReadFileAndStoreHashmap {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(".txt"));

            HashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
                map.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
                System.out.println(map);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks wrong to me: `new FileReader(".txt")`. (Also, please try to format your code more sensibly. The braces are all over the place here.)

Comment: could you please provide example content of `colorsANDnumbersWrite.data` file?

Comment: All I can think of is that it's reading a blank line, which implies that calling `scanner.nextLine()` is resulting in a blank line. I suggest debugging and stepping through line by line to read what `columns` is being read in as.

Comment: and what does a print of columns  and the nextLine show? Usually printing out a variable just before a bug gives useful info?

Comment: My input looks something like this:Mary ID
Mary Lastname
Mary Place
Mary DOB
Mary Homepage
Mary Postcode
John ID
John Lastname
John Place
John DOB
John Homepage
John Postcode

Answer (score 3):

I would check the line you're attempting to scan. I suspect it's blank and hence the scanner can't split it as desired.

I would recommend asserting/checking on the length of the returned array. If it doesn't have 2 elements then you can easily report this and continue or break as desired, whilst reporting to the user what's gojne wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have an empty line somewhere (does you file end with a newline? Then there is an empty line after it, probably.)

add a check like

```
if(columns.length == 2)
```

Comment: @user1549861 please mark the answer that helped you most as correct (by clicking the hook left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use BufferedReader personally.

Here is my suggestion:

```
try {
    String line;
    BufferedReader filestart = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    for (line = filestart.readLine(); line !=null; line = filestart.readLine()) {

          String[] columns = line.split(" ");
          map.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
          System.out.println(map);

    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Having "line != null" should ensure you can definitely split the line, before you try.